# Powershell I would like to look for a Name in a CSV and return their email in the textbox

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to have a `CSV` file with everyone's Name and Email address. then what I would like to do within a `GUI` type just their name into a `textbox` and it will return an email address.

I am currently using an `if` statement as I have tested it with just one user.

```
$text = $textbox1.text
if($text -like Jake){

    $textbox4.visible = $true
    $textbox4.text = "Jake@hotmail.com"
}else{
    $textbox4.visible = $false
}
}
```

obviously this is not the best idea ^^^ that's why I think have a separate `CSV` and it can us that as the look up. any help with this would be awesome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was much simpler then I thought.

```
$text = $textbox1.text
$csv = Import-Csv "path to csv"
ForEach($User in $CSV){
If($user.Name -eq '$text'){
$text = '$user.outcome'
}
}
```

My CSV headers were Name and Outcome